# PHP: Write Fatal Error to custom log

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that occasionally throws an `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException:` depending on the error type. This causes my PHP script to stop processing.

I need to capture that error in a custom log file and write it to disk. I'm aware that I can see it if I enable error logging in php.ini, but I need to be able to capture it myself and write it to a custom error log file.

This is the error message I recieve

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Access to this data is temporarily disabled
  thrown in /var/script.php on line 1092
```

This is the piece of code that it refers to in script.php:

```
  protected function throwAPIException($result) {
    $e = new FacebookApiException($result);
    switch ($e->getType()) {
      // OAuth 2.0 Draft 00 style
      case 'OAuthException':
        // OAuth 2.0 Draft 10 style
      case 'invalid_token':
        // REST server errors are just Exceptions
      case 'Exception':
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        if ((strpos($message, 'Error validating access token') !== false) ||
            (strpos($message, 'Invalid OAuth access token') !== false) ||
            (strpos($message, 'An active access token must be used') !== false)
        ) {
          $this->destroySession();
        }
        break;
    }
    throw $e;
  }
```

Line 1092 is `$e = new FacebookApiException($result);`

Is there any way that I can capture that exception? I have tried adding the following under `case 'OAuthException':` but it didn't work:

```
$message = $e->getMessage();
    if (strpos($message, 'Access to this data is temporarily disabled') !== false)
        {
        $this->destroySession();
        file_put_contents($filename, $message);
        }
    break;
    throw $e;
```

Anything I can do to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `try/catch` to catch an exception.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, Just had a quick look, yes, I think this is what I need to do. I'm inheriting some existing code and my PHP is not that good, so I'll need to try and figure this out. But yes, I think I need to improve the existing code to include try/throw/catch Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## I see 2 changes that would be helpful.

1. As the comment by @barmar suggests you can use **throw, try, catch**. This is the "modern" and probably best way to solve this. However this is not always possible and you can't account for everything.
2. Set a **custom error handler**: `set_error_handler('errorHandler');` With this directive when an error is encountered it will drop into a function you specify. You do need to be careful as an error in your errorHandler will be devastating to your code. In that function you can open a log file and specify it's name, location, and contents. You can even conditionalize multiple log files based on the type of error, location, and message. Define the handler with 'function errorHandler($severity, $message, $file, $line){}' See php.net [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php),

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at this option also. I have some good pointers to go on here to investigate how to capture the error.